# Reshaping JSON output from a grouped dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have an R dataframe of the form:

```
Country Region  Year    V1  V2
AAAA    XXXX    2001    12  13
BBBB    YYYY    2001    14  15
AAAA    XXXX    2002    36  56
AAAA    XXXX    1999    45  67
```

and would like to generate a JSON equivalent of the form:

```
[
  {"Country": "AAAA",
   "Region":"XXXX",
    "V1": [ [1999,45], [2001,12] , [2002,36] ],
    "V2":[ [1999,67], [2001,13] , [2002,56] ]
  },
  {"Country": "BBBB",
   "Region":"YYYY",
   "V1":[ [2001,14] ],
   "V2":[ [2001,15] ]
  }
]
```

I'm imagining this requires:

1. grouping by Country and Region
2. sorting by Year within the groups
3. for each of the remaining columns Vx in V1, V2 (an arbitrary number of columns which may have arbitrary names), generating a list that contains list elements [Year, Vx], for ordered Year

but am struggling to find a way to do it?

Comment: Are you aware of the RJSONIO, rjson, and df2json packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way to do this.

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("Country Region  Year    V1  V2
AAAA    XXXX    2001    12  13
BBBB    YYYY    2001    14  15
AAAA    XXXX    2002    36  56
AAAA    XXXX    1999    45  67"), header = TRUE)
```

We add two helper functions to zip vectors together and a custom sort function which sorts a list by elements in a given position.

```
#' Pluck element
pluck_ = function (element){
  function(x) x[[element]]
}

#' Zip two vectors
zip_ <- function(..., names = F){
  x = list(...)
  y = lapply(seq_along(x[[1]]), function(i) lapply(x, pluck_(i)))
  if (names) names(y) = seq_along(y)
  return(y)
}

#' Sort a vector based on elements at a given position
sort_ <- function(v, i = 1){
  v[sort(sapply(v, '[[', i), index.return = T)$ix]
}
```

Time to put things together and use the `split-apply-combine` magic to get the output you seek.

```
library(plyr)
dat2 <- dlply(dat, .(Country, Region), function(d){
  list(
    Country = d$Country[1],
    Region = d$Region[1],
    V1 = sort_(zip_(d$Year, d$V1)),
    V2 = sort_(zip_(d$Year, d$V2))
  )
})
cat(rjson::toJSON(setNames(dat2, NULL)))
```

This gives you the output

```
[
  {"Country":"AAAA",
   "Region":"XXXX",
   "V1":[[1999,45],[2001,12],[2002,36]],
   "V2":[[1999,67],[2001,13],[2002,56]]
  },
  {"Country":"BBBB",
   "Region":"YYYY",
   "V1":[[2001,14]],
   "V2":[[2001,15]]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi Ramnath - I think I need to go away and properly get my head round  R data manipulations! As you maybe guess, there a possible rCharts spin-off for this.. the data shape I need is to feed a Mike Bostock originated d3 motion chart such as  http://bl.ocks.org/psychemedia/raw/7199905/

Comment: Nice! I glanced through the code. There seem to be some hardcoded values that depend on the data. If you strip all the data off the code, then you can write a simple rCharts wrapper. I will take a crack at this when I find time.

Comment: Argghh- where does pluck_() come from? I guess it's just a dev version of pluck() from library(hof)?

Comment: My bad. Just added it.

Comment: Thanks:-) Re: the hardcoded vals, I did a quick pass through the code looking for hardcoded values, and tried to handle them. Example here: https://gist.github.com/psychemedia/7199905#file-index-template-html

Comment: That looks good. You can easily create a reusable rCharts library based on this. Check this [short tutorial](http://rcharts.io/howitworks/) on how to go about it and ping me on twitter/github if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sort of messy function to do this (you could easily add sorting by year of the V1 and V2 arrays):

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection(
'Country Region  Year    V1  V2
AAAA    XXXX    2001    12  13
BBBB    YYYY    2001    14  15
AAAA    XXXX    2002    36  56
AAAA    XXXX    1999    45  67'
), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(plyr); library(RJSONIO)
myfunc <- function(nn)
{
  tt <- split(nn, nn$Country)
  bar <- function(w){
    foo <- function(x, y, z) paste(x[y], x[z], sep=",")
    V1 <- as.character(apply(w, 1, foo, y="Year", z="V1"))
    V2 <- as.character(apply(w, 1, foo, y="Year", z="V2"))
    datlist <- list(Country = unique(w$Country), 
                    Region = unique(w$Region), 
                    V1 = V1, V2=V2)
  }
  datlist <- lapply(tt, bar)
  names(datlist) <- NULL
  RJSONIO::toJSON(datlist)
}

cat(myfunc(dat))

[
 {
   "Country": "AAAA",
   "Region": "XXXX",
   "V1": [ "2001,12", "2002,36", "1999,45" ],
   "V2": [ "2001,13", "2002,56", "1999,67" ] 
 },
 {
   "Country": "BBBB",
   "Region": "YYYY",
   "V1": "2001,14",
   "V2": "2001,15" 
  } 
]
```

Comment: Hi Scott - thanks for that; it's nearly there though the consumer Javascript I'm dealing with needs the V elements to be lists of lists  eg "V2":[ [1999,67], [2001,13] , [2002,56] ]. I was wondering if there was a ddply and dcast way in but keep getting horribly confused!

Comment: just added reading table in for reproducibility...Cool, I figured Ramnath might know how to do this!